How can I get the Serialized-ID token from Keyclaok so I can set cookies on a WKWebView in a SwiftUI app?
I'm trying to set cookies on a WKWebView so a user is logged in, however, I don't know how to get the necessary cookies or data to construct the cookies myself.
For a user to be logged in the AUTH_SESSION_ID, KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY and KEYCLOAK_SESSION cookies need to be set. For the AUTH_SESSION_ID and KEYCLOAK_SESSION cookies I think I have enough data to create them myself, but the KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY cookie contains a Serialized-ID token which I don't know how to get.
Is there an endpoint or request I can make to Keycloak to fetch the Serialized-ID token (or all three cookies pre-made)?
The WebView looks like this:
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
        let expirationDate = formatter.date(from: "2024/07/20 23:33:41")

        let cookies = [
            HTTPCookie(properties: [
                .name: "AUTH_SESSION_ID",
                .value: "cookie-value",
                .domain: "example.com",
                .path: "/path",
                .init(rawValue: "HttpOnly"): true,
                .secure: true,
                .sameSitePolicy: "None"
            ],
            HTTPCookie(properties: [
                .name: "IDENTITY",
                .value: "cookie-value",
                .domain: "example.com",
                .path: "/path",
                .init(rawValue: "HttpOnly"): true,
                .secure: true,
                .sameSitePolicy: "None"
            ],
            HTTPCookie(properties: [
                .name: "SESSION",
                .value: "cookie-value",
                .domain: "example.com",
                .path: "/path",
                .expires: expirationDate as NSDate?
                .init(rawValue: "HttpOnly"): false,
                .secure: true,
                .sameSitePolicy: "None"
            ]
        ]

        for cookie in cookies {
            configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie)
        }

        return WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}

And it is used in the ContentView like this:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            WebView(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/home")!)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }

            WebView(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/me")!)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Me", systemImage: "person")
                }
        }
    }
}

Curiously, when printing the cookies at the end of the makeUIView function (before returning the webView) there are no cookies, but after switching to the Me tab there are.
configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { cookies in
    print("Got \(cookies.count) cookies")
    for cookie in cookies {
        print("Cookie: \(cookie.name) = \(cookie.value)")
    }
}

